# Please check my example about jquery autocomple with servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

Please check my code, did i get some things wrong
I'm a newbie in jquery and ajax, please check and show me how to fix this

In jsp page :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX calls using Jquery in Servlet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    var availableTags = [];
    function getData (request, response) {
        var value = [];
        var username = $('#user').val();
        $.get('autocompleteServlet', {user : username}, function(responseText){
            $('#welcometext').text(responseText);
            value = [responseText];
            response(value);
        });
        return value;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {                       
        $('#user').keydown(function(){
            availableTags = getData(request, response);
        });
        $('#user').autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <h1>AJAX Demo using Jquery in JSP and Servlet</h1>
        Enter your Name: <input type="text" id="user" />
        <div id="welcometext"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my servlet :

```
@Override protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String value = request.getParameter("user");
    System.out.println("user : "+ value);

    try {
        Connection cnn = XJdbc.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT Name FROM reported_tasks WHERE Name LIKE '%"+ value + "%'";
        Statement stm = cnn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        String result = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            result = result + rs.getString("Name") + ",";
        }
        cnn.close();
        System.out.println("Request :" + result);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: do you need to fix it?  does it work?

Comment: Are you aware that building a query out of user-supplied data is a very bad idea? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2):

I can't talk for the java part, but here's my two cents on your js.

#### favor placing scripts at the bottom of your page.

...just before the `</body>`tag. Many reasons to do so can be found [out there](http://codecraftingblueprints.com/put-scripts-at-the-bottom/) ; mainly it's because script links in the `<head>` block page loading while the external js is being loaded and parsed.

#### use a closure

Your `availableTags` var is in global scope. If you want to avoid this, use a closure :

```
// create a function and execute it immediatly, effectively encapsulating vars :
(function(){ var my = "myvar"; })();

// same thing with a function expression - one less keystroke \o/  
!function(){ var my = "myvar"; }();
```

#### cache your jquery elements

Looking for an element in the DOM is expensive, you want to avoid doing it multiple times for the same element whenever it's possible. Just store the element in a var and use it in your function calls and callbacks.

#### getData doesn't return what you think it returns

sure, you return `value`. But just before you issue an AJAX request, that is an *asynchronous* (non blocking) request. What happens here is that the browser fires the request, but doesn't wait for an answer to go on and return `value` immediately - potentialy before your callback even has a chance to change `value`.

That's why you have to use callbacks. Given all these remarks, I would go for something like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX calls using Jquery in Servlet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <h1>AJAX Demo using Jquery in JSP and Servlet</h1>
        Enter your Name: <input type="text" id="user" />
        <div id="welcometext"></div>
    </form>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        !function(){

            var availableTags = [],
                $user         = $('#user'),
                $welcome      = $('#welcometext');

            $user.keydown(function(){
              $.get('autocompleteServlet', {user : $user.val()}, function(responseText){
                $welcome.text(responseText);
                availableTags.push(responseText);
                // fire update for your autocomplete ?      
              });
            });

            $user.autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
            });

        }();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```